# SNMP4J retry policy

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I've implemented simple SNMP Traps Collector with the following `CommandResponder`:

```
new CommandResponder() {

    @Override
    public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent event) {
        PDU pdu = event.getPDU();
        Trap receivedTrap = snmpHelper.toTrap(pdu);
        trapStorage.offer(receivedTrap);
    }
};
```

When I send some traps to the collector with the following `Target` settings in the sender:

```
target.setRetries(2);
target.setTimeout(500);
```

SNMP Collector receives the trap 3 times. 
Why? Should I send some response back to sender from the collector in order to prevent the trap from being resend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of SNMP notifications (by PDU types):

- Trapv1
- Trapv2 (since SNMPv2)
- Inform (since SNMPv2)

The big problem with TRAPs is that they're unacknowledged so the SNMP Agent does not actually know if the SNMP Manager received it. SNMPv2 PDUs fixed this by introducing the notion of an INFORM, which is nothing more than an acknowledged TRAP. So  I believe the agent you deal with sends the same trap three times just to make sure it gets delivered.

To prevent this problem you should consider using INFORMs if the agent supports them. Also it is possible that there is some sort of configuration option on the agent/device side that will allow you to disable this behavior.